# MongoDB: How to perform spatial queries on nested location properties?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    name: "John",
    addresses: [
        {
            city: "London",
            location: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [0, 0]
            }
        },
        {
            city: "New York",
            location: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-74, 40]
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Joanna",
    addresses: [
        // Similar array of her addresses
    ]
}
```

Now, I have a coordinate `x = (0.0001, 0.0001)`. I want to get all the people in my collection that have an address close to this point **and get only those addresses in the response**. For the query coordinate as `x`, I want only John's first address in the response:

```
{
    name: "John",
    addresses: [
        {
            city: "London",
            location: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [0, 0]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have seen similar examples, but they all return the entire document, i.e. they'd return all of John's addresses. How do I return only the **addresses** (there may be more than one, hence the `$` operator won't work), that are near the query coordinate `x`?

P.S. - I did try unwinding and then checking (using the aggregation framework), but that doesn't allow me to use a spatial query anywhere else except for the first stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

First, You should check how many addresses exist. Then if more than 0 you could use slice method. If address array length is zero then return the null.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    {$addFields: {'addressCount': {$size: '$addresses'}}},
    {$addFields: {'firstAddress': {
        $cond: {
            if: { $gt: ['$addressCount', 0]},
            then: { "$slice" : [ "$addresses" , 0, 1 ] },
            else: null
        }}
    }},
    "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "firstAddress" : 1
    }
}
])
```

Comment: How does this give me the addresses that are `$near` a given point `x`?